# Java servlet, respond after recieving each request before queuing

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am using Java servlets using Apache tomcat.

I've configured a threadpool and am dealing with each request. 
My page is taking in many GET requests at the same time, I'm wondering if I can respond to the server after each get request before any of the logic happens?

So server gives me a request -> I respond with either 'good send another' or 'bad send another' before I start my queueing.

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT

Sorry that was terribly written :(

What I'm asking for is a way to send a Header to the client (in this case it's a server which sends me lots of requests). The response would just be 200 or error based on the information I get sent.

What my program is doing: 
My servlet gets sent lots of GET requests from one client. (over 100,000) Which I am using tomcat to queue and put into a threadpool. It is then assigned to a worker thread which processes it and puts it into a database.

I've been told to do is send a request back to that server saying 'ok received it'. I think I can use a header response but I don't have the URL of that client (and the client can change for different campaigns). So was wondering what the best way would be to send that response.

After doing some more research I think what I'm looking for is ServletOutputStream.

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
    ServletOutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();

    output.flush();
    output.close();
```

Using servlet output stream where do I set the `<head><body>` tag? and insert the header response afterwards.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: At least these points are unclear to me: server gives your requests? Aren't requests from clients? What do you mean by "logic"? What queueing are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is "sure".

If these are get requests from a web page for a web page, include a refresh timer and send back some token that can be used to identify the difference between a first-time-request and an I-requested-earlier-are-you-done request.  In this case the refresh timer can be set via a meta refresh tag.

If the get requests are part of a REST API then you can define "got it and I'm working" into the protocol.  For instance, return a 202 to indicate "got it but not done" and return 200 to indicate "done".  As with the html page, consider sending some token back with the 202 that identifies the pending request.